# Создание копирующего конструктора

Tags: java

Создаём копию другого прямоугольника (он и передаётся в параметрах):

```
public class Rectangle {
  private int left, top, width, height;
  Rectangle p;

  public Rectangle(int left, int top, int width, int height) {
    this.left = left;
    this.top = top;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
  }

  public Rectangle(Rectangle p) {
    p.top = this.top;
    p.left = this.left;
    p.width = this.width;
    p.height = this.height;
  }
}
```

Почему передаются параметры из переменных главного класса? Разве они не остаются пустыми?

Comment: Мой вопрос скорей в обратном. Как создать копию конструктора?

Comment: Что такое "копирующий треугольник"? Может быть вы имели в виду "пикирующий треугольник", то есть тот, который умеет немножко летать?

Comment: Какой-то весьма странный конструктор копирования. В нем, как минимум, нужно поменять местами то, что стоит слева от знака `=` с тем, что стоит справа от него.

Comment: Какие можно скопировать конструктор? Я вижу что он странный :)

Comment: @HelloGoogle Он выглядит симметрично относительно первого конструктора. Не находите?

Comment: Я понял как нужно было создать объект в классе и ему присваивать значения :)

Comment: Rectangle (Rectangle rect){
          rect.top = this.top;
          rect.left = this.left;
          rect.width = this.width;
          rect.height = this.height;
     }

Comment: Объект забыл найти в своём коде

Comment: Почему вообще у вас внутри класса `Rectangle` хранится ещё один `Rectangle` в качестве поля?

Comment: @Regent задание выглядит так: /* Создать класс прямоугольник (Rectangle)
Создать класс прямоугольник (Rectangle). Его данными будут top, left, width, height (левая координата, верхняя, ширина и высота). Создать для него как можно больше конструкторов:
Примеры:
- заданы 4 параметра: this.centerX = centerX;
        this.centerY = centerY;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.width = width;
- ширина/высота не задана (оба равны 0)
- высота не задана (равно ширине) создаём квадрат
- создаём копию другого прямоугольника (он и передаётся в параметрах)
*/

Comment: Я только часть своего кода засунул сюда. Первый конструктор и последний.

Comment: Создание как можно большего количества конструкторов никоим образом не требует хранить `Rectangle` внутри `Rectangle`. Это вообще выглядит весьма противоестественно.

Comment: @Regent Я не совсем понял что вы имеете в виду. Куда мне тогда записывать копию?

Comment: @HelloGoogle а зачем вам записывать копию? И вы понимаете, что при таком подходе вы рискуете уйти в бесконечную рекурсию, потому что у копии будет своя копия и т.д. и одно неловкое движение приведёт к созданию бесконечного количества `Rectangle`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Способ клонирования объекта, который Вы хотите реализовать, будет выглядеть вот так:

```
public class Rectangle {
    private int left, top, width, height;

    public Rectangle(int left, int top, int width, int height) {
        this.left = left;
        this.top = top;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public Rectangle(Rectangle p) {
        this(p.left, p.top, p.width, p.height);
    }
}
```

Здесь в конструктор `Rectangle(Rectangle p)` передается объект `Rectangle p`, с данными которого вызывается конструктор `Rectangle(int left, int top, int width, int height)`.

Answer (score 1):

В этом случае может помочь метод `java.lang.Object.clone()`. Чтобы его использовать класс должен выглядеть так:

```
public class Rectangle implements Cloneable {
    private int left, top, width, height;

    public Rectangle(int left, int top, int width, int height) {
        this.left = left;
        this.top = top;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    @Override
    public Rectangle clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return (Rectangle) super.clone();
    }
}
```

Тогда, чтобы получить копию, достаточно лишь вызвать метод:

```
 Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(1, 2, 4, 5);
 Rectangle r2 = r1.clone();
```